# How can I expand a vector into the arguments of a function in r?

Tags: r

If I have the function with three individual arguments

```
fun <- function(a,b,c){
    a+b^2*c
}
```

How can I call it using a single vector

```
my_vector <- c(1,2,3)
fun(my_vector)
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

try this:

```
> do.call("fun", as.list(my_vector))
[1] 13
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work!

```
fun(1,2,3)
```

Otherwise,

```
fun <- function(x){
                   x[1]+x[2]^2*x[3]
                   }
fun(c(1,2,3))
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue of needing to expand a list into function arguments, which is particularly important when you're using an existing function.