# How to rbind matrices based on objects names?

Tags: r, rbind

I have several matrices that I would like to `rbind` in a single summary one. They are objects product of different functions and they have share a pattern in their names.

What I want to do is to tell R to look for all the objects with that common pattern and then `rbind` them.

Assuming these matrices exist:

```
commonname.N1<-matrix(nrow=2,ncol=3)
commonname.N2<-matrix(nrow=2,ncol=3)
commonname.M1<-matrix(nrow=2,ncol=3)
```

I tried something like this to get them:

```
mats<-grep(x= ls(pos=1), pattern="commonname.", value=TRUE)
mats
[1] "commonname.N1" "commonname.N2" "commonname.M1"
```

What I can't figure out is how to tell `rbind` to use that as argument. Basically I would something that gives the same matrix than what `rbind(commonname.N1, commonname.N2, commonname.M1)` would do in this example.

I have tried things on the line of

```
mats<-toString(mats)
rbind(mats2)
```

but that just creates a matrix with the different objects as names.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269221/how-can-i-expand-a-vector-into-the-arguments-of-a-function-in-r), but:

```
mats<-as.list(mats)
do.call(what=rbind, args=as.list(mats))
```

doesn't do the job.

Sorry if there is something basic I'm missing somewhere, but I can't figure it out and I'm relatively new to R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `mget`:

```
do.call(rbind,mget(mats))
```

Comment: Cheers, just had to add envir = .GlobalEnv to make it work. `do.call(rbind,mget(mats, envir = .GlobalEnv))`